# Trying to get user appointments from outlook and display in my winform that contains a listbox?

Tags: c#, listbox, outlook-2010

I have an application that get the users information from active directory: **So my question is am i doing the right thing in the below code that deals with getting the appointments from outlook?**

**I am using vs 2008 with outlook 2010**

```
 private void ShowUserInformation(SearchResult rs)
    {

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value != null)
            username.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["givenName"].Value != null)
            FirstName.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["initials"].Value != null)
            MiddleName.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["initials"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sn"].Value != null)
            LastName.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sn"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value != null)
            email.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["company"].Value != null)
            company.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["company"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["l"].Value != null)
            city.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["l"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["st"].Value != null)
            state.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["st"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["co"].Value != null)
            country.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["co"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["memeberOf = IS Team"].Value != null)
            Groups.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["memeberOf = IS Team"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["postalCode"].Value != null)
            postalcode.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["postalCode"].Value.ToString();

        phone.Text = "";
        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value != null)
            phone.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString();
        else phone.Text = "";

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["streetAddress"].Value != null)
            address.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["streetAddress"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["department"].Value != null)
            department.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["department"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["description"].Value != null)
            descriptions.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["description"].Value.ToString();

        mobile.Text = "";
        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mobile"].Value != null)
            mobile.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mobile"].Value.ToString();
        else mobile.Text = "";

        homedirectory.Text = "";
        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["homeDirectory"].Value != null)
            homedirectory.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["homeDirectory"].Value.ToString();
        else homedirectory.Text = "";

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["whenCreated"].Value != null)
            WhenCreate.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["whenCreated"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["whenChanged"].Value != null)
            whenchanged.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["whenChanged"].Value.ToString();


    }
```

Now i am trying to get the appointments of that user(using his mail property) from outlook and display in a lisbox so i did some reading online and found this code from microsoft website:

```
private void DemoAppointmentsInRange()
{
Outlook.Folder calFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolderOutlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)as Outlook.Folder;
DateTime start = StartTime.Value; //datetimepicker 1 start date (letting the user select the range)
DateTime end = EndTime.Value; //datetimepicker 1 start date (letting the user select the range)
Outlook.Items rangeAppts = GetAppointmentsInRange(calFolder, start, end);
if (rangeAppts != null)
{
    foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem appt in rangeAppts)
    {
        Appoinments.Items.Add("Subject: " + appt.Subject 
            + " Start: " + appt.Start.ToString("g"));
    }
}
}

**/// <summary>
/// Get recurring appointments in date range.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="folder"></param>
/// <param name="startTime"></param>
/// <param name="endTime"></param>
/// <returns>Outlook.Items</returns>**

private Outlook.Items GetAppointmentsInRange(
    Outlook.Folder folder, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        string filter = "[Start] >= '"
            + startTime.ToString("g")
            + "' AND [End] <= '"
            + endTime.ToString("g") + "'";
        Debug.WriteLine(filter);
        try
        {
            Outlook.Items calItems = folder.Items;
            calItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;
            calItems.Sort("[Start]", Type.Missing);
            Outlook.Items restrictItems = calItems.Restrict(filter);
            if (restrictItems.Count > 0)
            {
                return restrictItems;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }
```

**After Constant Search on google i found this code that i used so now i am able to fill the listbox with appoinments but its my personal appointments now how do i pass the username or user's email into the code below to get their appoinments?**

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.RecurrencePattern recurrencePattern;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace oNS;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder oCalendar;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items oItems;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppt;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application _OutlookApplication;
            try
            {
                _OutlookApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                oNS = _OutlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");

                // Get the Calendar folder.
                oCalendar = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

                oCalendar.Items.IncludeRecurrences = true;


                // Get the Items (Appointments) collection from the Calendar folder.
                oItems = oCalendar.Items;


                for (Int32 x = 1; x <= oItems.Count; x++)
                {
                    //Need to change how we are getting the appointment
                    //Apparently Outlook will return non-appointments in the calendar feed
                    try
                    {
                        oAppt = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)oItems[x];
                        Appointments.Items.Add(oAppt.Subject);

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (oAppt.Body != null)
                        Console.WriteLine("      Calendar Body:" + oAppt.Body.ToString());

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: what makes you think you are not doing the right thing? is there an error?

Comment: @eddie_cat i receive this error                                            Error 1 The type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application' exists in both 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office11\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll' and 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll' C:\Users\israa\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\UserExtract\UserExtract\Form1.cs 382 21 UserExtract

Comment: Looks like you have two versions of the same dll in two places and it's not sure which one to use.

Comment: I am not sure which ones to delete, will that affect my real time outlook mail application? is there workaround for this situation??

Comment: @eddie_cat I added some extra code that works to fill in the list-box but it fills it up with my appointments, now can you tell me how i would be able to pass the username or email into it to get their appointments?